# Display banner over AVPlayer from a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, wkwebview

I'm creating an app to watch live streams from the internet using a table view that opens AVPlayer when a cell is tapped. There are some cases that I can't open streams directly and so I have to use a WKWebView and then the video is opened by this one. I have to put a banner as overlay in AVPlayer and I managed to do it when the player is opened directly; the question is: how can I access to the AVPlayer properties when this is called by a WKWebView?

I tried to add an extension to the AVPlayerViewController class to manage the banner and it works well with the videos I open directly, but my solution seems to be useless with WKWebView-based videos...
Is AVPlayerViewController that manages videos opened by a WKWebView or another class?

Comment: Can you find any solution for this if you can help me see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview